# Left alignment of <img> within a bootstrap grid system

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I'm trying to put and left align an image within a column but the img is always automatically centered within a colum. I'm not so familiar with Bootstrap and I would be happy if you could show me the reason why it doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h1>Basic</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>test</p>
            <!--Portfolio Container-->        
            <div class="container-fluid text-center pull-left bg-grey">
                <div class="row" border>
                    <div class="col-lg-12" width="100%">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris">
                            <p><strong>Yes we built Paris</strong></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like type.less has a .text-center: center; attached

Comment: ist i would like to mention <div class="col-lg-12" width="100%"> . there is no need to set width to 100% as col-lg-12 will do it itself. now sol for your question. use text-left to left align image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text-center class used to center align content inside column , Remove text-center class from the parent container-fluid or override the css

```
  <style>
   .thumbnail img
    {
      text-align:left;
    }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `text-center` from the parent `container-fluid`..

```
     <div class="container-fluid pull-left bg-grey">
              <div class="row" border="">
                     <div class="col-lg-12" width="100%">
                              <div class="thumbnail">
                                  <img src="paris.jpg" alt="Paris">
                                  <p><strong>Yes we built Paris</strong></p>
                               </div>
                     </div>
              </div>
      </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/HOONi5zSpD